# Can't import local module? PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I got issue with relative and absolute imports with PyCharm

Project structure:

[image]

When I'm trying to import a local Package like this I'm getting error

[image]

But this works fine:
[image]

What should be done so that both PyCharm and Python do not give out an error?

Comment: You are using a source layout, so you should have to install the project with `pip install -e .`

Comment: _"When I'm trying to import a local Package like this I'm getting error"_: what is the error?

Comment: Did you accidentally paste the pictures the wrong way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PyCharm to recognize a directory as a module, you need to mark it as a Sources Root. To do that, right click it, hover over "Mark Directory as" and click on "Sources Root".

Comment: The problem with this is that you aren't installing you project. So the code you are testing and implementing will work differently from when you install it.